# Add a list to specific lines of a (YAML) text file using python

Tags: command-line, python, text-processing

I have an Ansible module file for NetBox with this content:

```yaml
- name: "Test NetBox modules"
  connection: local
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
    - name: Create device within NetBox with only required information
      netbox.netbox.netbox_device:
        netbox_url: http://netbox.local
        netbox_token: thisIsMyToken
        data:
          name: xxxx
          device_type: 
          device_role: 
          site: Main
        state: present


    - name: Create device within NetBox with only required information
      netbox.netbox.netbox_device:
        netbox_url: http://netbox.local
        netbox_token: thisIsMyToken
        data:
          name: xxxx
          device_type: 
          device_role: 
          site: Main
        state: present

    - name: Create device within NetBox with only required information
      netbox.netbox.netbox_device:
        netbox_url: http://netbox.local
        netbox_token: thisIsMyToken
        data:
          name: xxxx
          device_type: 
          device_role: 
          site: Main
        state: present
```

It has 3 tasks for adding devices. I have a python list like this : `['switch1', 'switch2', 'switch3']`

my question is how can I add this elements of list in front of `name: xxxx` instead of `xxxx` regularly using python?

Comment: Hi mohammad, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is a pretty broad question, actually, since there are several different pieces involved in the task and it's not clear which one you are having trouble with. Could you add something to clarify that? For example, do you have a Python script and you're asking about how to run it? Or are you asking about how to read the file in Python? Or write it? Or how to replace a string with a different string? Or how to do different replacements in different parts of the file? Or so on....

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Python for this task (*too much work and reinventing the wheel*) ... I would use a specialized text processing tool that supports storing data sets e.g. arrays like [`awk`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/awk.1posix.html):

```
awk -F'[ ]' 'BEGIN {
    devices[1] = "switch1"
    devices[2] = "switch2"
    devices[3] = "switch3"
}

/name: xxxx/ {
    i++
    $NF = devices[i]
}

{
    print
}' file.yaml
```

which will output:

```
- name: "Test NetBox modules"
  connection: local
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
    - name: Create device within NetBox with only required information
      netbox.netbox.netbox_device:
        netbox_url: http://netbox.local
        netbox_token: thisIsMyToken
        data:
          name: switch1
          device_type: 
          device_role: 
          site: Main
        state: present


    - name: Create device within NetBox with only required information
      netbox.netbox.netbox_device:
        netbox_url: http://netbox.local
        netbox_token: thisIsMyToken
        data:
          name: switch2
          device_type: 
          device_role: 
          site: Main
        state: present

    - name: Create device within NetBox with only required information
      netbox.netbox.netbox_device:
        netbox_url: http://netbox.local
        netbox_token: thisIsMyToken
        data:
          name: switch3
          device_type: 
          device_role: 
          site: Main
        state: present
```

or [`gawk`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/gawk.1.html) to edit the file in place:

```
gawk -i inplace -F'[ ]' 'BEGIN {
        devices[1] = "switch1"
        devices[2] = "switch2"
        devices[3] = "switch3"
}

/name: xxxx/ {
        i++
        $NF = devices[i]
}

{
        print
}' file.yaml
```

**Notice**: You can still call `awk` or `gawk` from within a Python script with e.g. Python's [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) or [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) modules.